# Quiero hacer un buscador en mi App

Tags: mysql, flutter, buscador, dart

Buenas estoy haciendo un buscador en mi `app` y no se como continuar, tengo ahora mismo que cuando el usuario escribe algo lo muestro por terminal necesito hacerlo que lo muestre por pantalla pero no se como conseguirlo estoy trabajando con `Flutter`, gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Con este código lo que hago es consultar la base de datos y a medida que el usuario va escribiendo lo voy consultando y almacenando en datos, lo que quiero es mostrar por pantalla al usuario lo que tengo en datos, es decir lo que el usuario ha buscado. Se como mostrarlo por terminal pero no por pantalla. Supongo que de alguna forma tendré que actualizar la pantalla o la parte de la pantalla donde quiero que se muestre pero no se como.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class VerProducto extends StatelessWidget{

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
                title: new Text("Ver Producto"),
                textTheme: TextTheme(title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            ),
            body: BodyVerProducto(),
        );
    }
}

class BodyVerProducto extends StatelessWidget{

    final Controller1 = new TextEditingController();
    final nombre =  [];

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var settings3 = new ConnectionSettings(
            host: '',
            user: '',
            password: '',
            db: ''
        );

        return new Container(
            child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                    new FormBuilderTextField(
                        controller: Controller1,
                        onChanged: (value) async {
                            String v = value;
                            var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings3);

                            var datos = await conn.query('SELECT name FROM ps_product_lang WHERE name LIKE "%$value%" AND id_lang = 1',);

                            print(datos);

                        },
                    ),
                ],
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algo básico para que empieces, sería con `StatefulWidget`, y cada vez que obtengas el contenido, actualices el estado del Widget.

```
class BodyVerProducto extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyVerProductoState createState() => _BodyVerProductoState();
}

class _BodyVerProductoState extends State<BodyVerProducto> {
  final Controller1 = new TextEditingController();

  final nombre = [];

  var datos = [];

    var settings3 = new ConnectionSettings(
            host: '',
            user: '',
            password: '',
            db: ''
        );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: TextField(
              controller: Controller1,
              onChanged: (value) async {
                String v = value;
                var conn = await MySqlConnection.connect(settings3);

                setState(() {
                  datos = await conn.query(
                    'SELECT name FROM ps_product_lang WHERE name LIKE "%$value%" AND id_lang = 1',
                  );

                  print(datos);
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: datos.length,
              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text("Nombre: ${datos[index]['name']}"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Lo tengo asi ya pero no actualiza, lo que hace siempre es añadirme contenido debajo del actual, pero no actualiza nada, la unica forma que lo actualize es llamando en el OnChange el array de nombres para que se sobreescriba cada vez que modifico algo pero entonces no lo muestra por pantalla

Comment: Si esa IP con user y password que has publicado son reales, te recomiendo cambiarlo lo antes posible, antes de que sufras alguna intrusión a tu sistema.

Comment: Diego, como bien dice @Marc yo cambiaría lo antes posible las credenciales de acceso a tu web. He eliminado toda la información, pero aun así mejor que lo cambies, y que tengas mucho cuidado con estas cosas. Un saludo

Comment: @AcoidanNegrínSocorro , no entendí bien que es lo que no te funciona , puedes explicar mejor? según el código, cada vez que vas escribiendo , filtra en la base de datos y refresca el contenido de la lista